# Passing data HTML->HTML using POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

In the sending page I have the following code:

```
        var params = 'scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=1000,height=750,left=500,top=500';

        var tripWindow = open('tripinfo.htm?TRIPID=99999' ,'Add Trip', params);
        tripWindow.focus();
```

In the receiving page I have the following code:

```
TRIPID = <?php echo $_POST['TRIPID']?>;
```

However, the value of TRIPID is not being read. I checked using F12 and the value is being written out.

Fairly new to this. I am sure it's something dumb that I am missing.

Comment: `TRIPID` is a GET variable, not a POST variable. Use `TRIPID = <?php echo $_GET['TRIPID'] ?>;` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're making a GET request with the URL querystring, not a POST request. Try:

```
TRIPID = <?php echo $_GET['TRIPID']?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php